# Updating Aggregated tables with new sequence

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

**General Scenario:**

I have an aggregated table per user and date with several measures.
the table stores up to 10 records per user and date (could be less, depending on the user activity)
There is a column which is the sequence occurrence ordered by date.

Sample:

```
CREATE TABLE #Main (UserId int , DateId int , MeasureA numeric(20,2) , MeasureB numeric(20,2), PlayDaySeq int)
INSERT INTO #Main 
    VALUES (188,    20180522    ,75.00,     282287.00,  1),
           (188,    20180518    ,250.00,    1431725.00, 2),
           (188,    20180514    ,25.00,     35500.00,   3),
           (188,    20180513    ,115.00,    67100.00,   4),
           (188,    20180511    ,75.00,     10625.00,   5),
           (188,    20180510    ,40.00,     2500.00,    6),
           (188,    20180509    ,40.00,     750.00,     7),
           (188,    20180508    ,160.00,    16250.00,   8),
           (188,    20180507    ,135.00,    138200.00,  9),
           (188,    20180507    ,150.00,    68875.00,   10)
```

The Column `PlayDaySeq` is calculated as `ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY DateId DESC)`

and here is the table that will hold the new aggregated data for this is user:

```
CREATE TABLE #Inc (UserId int , DateId int , MeasureA numeric(20,2) , MeasureB numeric(20,2), PlayDaySeq int)
INSERT INTO #Inc
    VALUES (188,    20180523    ,225.00,    802921.00,  1)
```

Now, a new record is available so I used The following:

```
INSERT INTO #Main
    SELECT * 
     FROM #Inc I
        WHERE NOT EXISTS 
            (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM #Main M
            WHERE i.UserId = M.UserId
            AND i.DateId = M.DateId
            )
```

**The Question is**

I need to update the `PlayDaySeq` column so the new record will 1 and all the rest will increment by 1 
and delete the records that their sequence will be greater than 10

What is the best way of doing that? 
keep in mind that the #main table is pretty large (250M records).

I can update the sequence by running the `ROW_NUMBER` again, and then `DELETE` the ones that will be greater than 10, 
I'm looking for the most efficient way to do that.

Comment: What is the point of using a column like `PlayDaySeq`? Using `ROW_NUMBER`, as already described in your post, you can easily assign a sequence number to each row.

Comment: The column has a business meaning as we have several calculations that depends on it, for example how many days passed between play date 3 and play date 7.

Comment: I don't want to update the large table more than I have to.

Comment: First choice: use a view. Second: trigger.

Comment: I'd rather not using a trigger, this is a large table and triggers affect performance.

Answer (score 1):

Updating one row resulting an update of every other single record does not sounds a good idea despite how infrequently it is. Like the comment already mentioned that I don't see the need of such a column.
But you stated you have you reason so I will assume that is true.

My suggestion is drop PlayDaySeq on the table and create a view with following as additional column.

```
ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY DateId DESC) AS PlayDaySeq
```

And then whatever your code was using that table now should use the view, should keep the change minimal. But you need to test this out see what's the performance like. Also if you changing the view to indexed view, SQL server stores the value as a table like thing, which when you insert new record it would automatically update things for you, again you need test performance, on insert.

If I were you I would be more willing to try a different approach, such as instead of make it 1,2,3 I set it to 100,200,300, hence when insertion need are smaller like 20 records a day I then never need update rest record but just put in 11,12 101,102 which would still keeps the order correct, and a nightly job to update whole table to be 100,200,300 again for a fresh start next day, or make the code to only do it when running out of numbers, , but due to how you are using it as you state this other meaning, it may not work at all.

Comment: I'll try using a view, I need to do some testing regarding performance as querying the table + additional calculation of ROW_NUMBER can be pretty "heavy"